# How to refer to another model in xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am using MVVM and embedding models within XAML, some models are constructed standalone, but one of the models need to refer to another one in construction, because the data in db also needs to refer to it, I couldn't find a way to do it in XAML, the XAML is like this:

```
     <models:UserModel x:Key="UserModel"></models:UserModel>
     <models:OrderModel x:Key="OrderModel">
         <x:Arguments>
              {StaticResource UserModel} // what tag to use here?
         </x:Arguments>
     </models:OrderModel>
```

Is there any right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `StaticResource` is a markup extension, you can use it either through [attribute usage, or element usage](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/d108dfe17652d3f6a18bf76d0b7f955b74244998/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml/MarkupExtensions/StaticResourceExtension.cs)

```
 <models:OrderModel x:Key="OrderModel">
     <x:Arguments>
          <StaticResource Key="UserModel" />
     </x:Arguments>
 </models:OrderModel>
```

**EDIT - 1**

Looks like when you use `StaticResource` inside `x:Arguments` - it just passes on the extension object to the constructor; instead of resolving it for value. Simplest way to resolve this would be to add a property to `OrderModel` to assign the `UserModel` object.

```
<local:UserModel x:Key="UserModel" />
<local:OrderModel x:Key="OrderModel" User="{StaticResource UserModel}"/>
```